# How can I send multiple commands to Interactive telnet/ssh session from command line?

Tags: ssh, cmd, telnet, batch-processing, putty

I have a problem with one of the tasks I'm working on at the moment. I have to execute 2 commands in the interactive telnet/ssh session from the level of command line.

I have managed to login to the server using plink command line, but then the difficult part comes, I have no idea how to pass 2 commands to it and end the session.

Normally I do it in PuTTY by loading a session, then typing in:

```
53 Enter
GIVE 5 next 3 Enter
```

and here I close the PuTTY window.

I want to automate it, but I fail to pass the commands that should be executed into `plink`. Maybe I should have used other tool, but I'm running out of ideas on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Create a file `input.txt` with content:

   ```
   53
   GIVE 5 next 3
   ```
2. Run `plink` like this:

   ```
   plink user@host < input.txt
   ```